# getting 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain 'result' Parsing with JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync

Tags: c#, .net, system.text.json

I have JSON in a response structured like this

```
{
   "statusCode": 200,
   "result": {
      "generalInfo": {
         "firstName": "",
         "lastName": ""
      },
      "isError": false      
   },
   "sentDate": "2022-02-06T10:04:06.6853775Z",
}

var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(address, model);
Stream responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

The response from the endpoint is actually a bit more complex and I want to extract only specific fields so I used dynamic

```
dynamic data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<dynamic>(responseBody)

var dataString = data.ToString();
```

// dataString  is

```
{"result":{"generalInfo":{"firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe"},"isError":false}
```

If I try to access dynamic properties like this

```
var firstName = data.result.generalInfo.firstName;
var lastName = data.result.generalInfo.lastName;
var isErr = data.IsError;
```

I'm getting exception

> 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' does not contain a definition for
> 'result'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is not `DeserializeAsync`, but that System.Text.Json uses `JsonElement`s, so the dynamic value is actually a `JsonElement`. You'll need to parse the data from the `JsonElement`.

However, if you're using .Net 6 you can use [`JsonNode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes.jsonnode?view=net-6.0):

```
// deserialize into JsonNode
JsonNode data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<JsonNode>(responseBody);
// OR parse the json string
JsonNode data = JsonNode.Parse(dataString);

int statusCode = (int)data["statusCode"];
var firstName = (string)data["result"]["generalInfo"]["firstName"];
var lastName = (string)data["result"]["generalInfo"]["lastName"];
var isErr = (bool)data["result"]["isError"];
```

[Demo in .Net6](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zUF4K0)

Support for `dynamic` was added to .Net 6 preview v4-6 but was removed before final release in favour of the `JsonNode` approach above. See github [What's new in .NET 6 Preview 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/6444#issuecomment-888533431) for further details.

---

Otherwise, you could parse it manually:

```
bool isError = false;
string firstName = ""; 
string lastName = "";
if (data is JsonElement elt && elt.TryGetProperty("result", out elt))
{
    isError = elt.TryGetProperty("isError", out JsonElement boolElt) ? boolElt.GetBoolean() : false;
    if (elt.TryGetProperty("generalInfo", out var genInfo))
    {
        firstName = genInfo.TryGetProperty("firstName", out var firstElt) ? firstElt.GetString() : "";
        lastName = genInfo.TryGetProperty("lastName", out var lastElt) ? lastElt.GetString() : "";
    }
}
```

---

However, my preferred approach is always to deserialize into defined classes if you can as it makes life much easier:

```
public class GeneralInfo
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public GeneralInfo generalInfo { get; set; }
    public bool isError { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

var data = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<Root>(responseBody);
var firstName = data.result.generalInfo.firstName;
```

Comment: What do you do when the json could be an item or an error message - different formats.